# Module Pattern Javascript

Tags: javascript

I experimenting with the module pattern in javascript. I have a main module `mainM` and `submoduls` which are loaded in with

```
var mainM = (function () {
    ...
    return { ... }
}());

var secM = (function (mainM) {
    ...
    mainM.func = function () { ... };
    return mainM;
}(mainM));
```

Now I want to split the `secM` into files and my goal is that **only** the `secM` can access the files. Is that possible?

It would be good if the modules are *submodules* of `secM` like `secM.nodes`.

Comment: you can't restrict anything that gets dumped to global in javascript.

Comment: So there is no chance to extend the submodul without making the extension public?

Comment: My goal is to extend the private methods of the submodule.

Comment: My only incentive to do this is that the file size would be bigger than 3k of code lines if I don't do this.

Comment: You might want to consider simply making some of the private methods public instead. Javascript isn't really good at doing "protected" methods - normally you either have something be completely private or completely public.